# Laravel Amazon s3 for prod but not dev

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-s3

I am trying to set up a dev environment for a Laravel app we have had written and the person who wrote it is not being overly helpful.  They use an Amazon S3 bucket to store the files but we want to have everything on our development server.  The PHP files seem to have 'https://domain.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/media/' hardcoded all over the place.  Any pointers as to how to unravel this and store files locally would be good.  Ideally having production on s3 and development and test environments using local filesystem (or maybe some type of service using the same protocol).  If not this then how do we modify the code so this stuff is not hardcoded.  we want to use the same code base for all environments in git.